# Mapping a type to another type in rust

Tags: rust, metaprogramming

I'm trying to write a rust (meta-)function that maps some input type to some unrelated output type.

Coming from a C++ background, I would usually write it like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct f;

template<>
struct f<int> { using type = double; };

using input_type = int;
using output_type = f<input_type>::type;
```

My naive attempt to write the same in rust looks like this:

```
macro_rules! f {
  ($in: ty) => {
    match $in {
      i32 => f32,
    }
  }
}

type OutputType = f!(i32);
```

but, well, this fails to compile because the macro apparently doesn't return a type.

```
$ rustc typedef.rs 
error: expected type, found keyword `match`
 --> typedef.rs:3:5
  |
3 |     match $in {
  |     ^^^^^ expected type
...
9 | type OutputType = f!(i32);
  |                   -------
  |                   |
  |                   this macro call doesn't expand to a type
  |                   in this macro invocation
  |
```

What's the idiomatic rust way to map one type to another?

Comment: I wasnt sure, so i checked what meta has to say: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338080/should-i-tag-language-a-if-i-ask-about-how-to-i-do-x-in-language-b-like-in-lang. c++ tag removed

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The reason your macro doesn't work is because of `match`. Your code `type OutputType = f!(i32);` will expand to:

```
type OutputType = match i32 {
    i32 => f32,
};
```

But you can't `match` over types. `match` only works for values. However, `macro_rules!` itself already has a pattern matching feature that operates on tokens. So you could write the macro like this:

```
macro_rules! f {
  (i32) => { f32 };
  (i64) => { f64 };
}

type OutputType = f!(i32);
```

But this is still very far away from your C++ example! A macro just operates on its input tokens meaning that this only works with a *literal* match. For example, this just doesn't work:

```
fn foo<T>() {
    let _: f!(T) = todo!();
}
```

This results in "error: no rules expected the token `T`".

To have a type-level function from one type to another, you want to use traits in Rust. For example:

```
trait F {
    type Out;
}

impl F for i32 {
    type Out = f32;
}

impl F for i64 {
    type Out = f64;
}

type OutputType = <i32 as F>::Out;

fn foo<T>() {
    // This works now.
    let _: <T as F>::Out = todo!();
}
```

There is a lot more to say about using traits like this. The whole system is Turing complete and people built lots of stuff in it. But this should suffice for this Q&A.

Answer (score 4):

The idiomatic way might be a `type` in a `trait`, e.g.

```rust
trait Matcher {
    type Output;
}

impl Matcher for i32 {
    type Output = f32;
}
```

However, if you want to use a `macro_rules!` macro, you need to match directly on the pattern. The `match` keyword is misleading, as your current macro expands to

```rust
    match i32 {
      i32 => f32,
    }
```

But `match` expects an expression, not a type. Instead, use the types for patterns:

```rust
macro_rules! f {
    (i32) => {
        f32
    };
    (i64) => {
        f64
    };
}

type OutputType = f!(i32);
```